# Creacion de usuarios locales (Poweshell)

Tags: powershell, cuenta-usuario

Estoy intentando hacer un *script* que cree usuarios. Pero me da error. ¿Me podríais ayudar?

La idea es crear un *script* que al ser ejecutado, de forma automática cree los usuarios, con nombre, contraseña (La predeterminada ha de ser el mismo nombre de usuario) y descripción.

Posteriormente el *script* ha de asignar a los usuarios a un grupo local.

--Codigo fuente--

```
#Script para crear usuarios en los terminales de Gerencia;
Clear-Host;
$PassG01= "dawsG01"
New-LocalUser -Name "dawsG01" -Password $PassG01 -Description "Usuario de Gerencia";
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administradores" -Member "dawsG01";
```

--texto de error--

```
New-LocalUser : No se puede enlazar el parámetro 'Password'. No se puede convertir el valor "dawsG01" de tipo "System.String" al tipo 
"System.Security.SecureString".
En línea: 4 Carácter: 41
+ New-LocalUser -Name "dawsG01" -Password $PassG01 -Description "Usuari ...
+                                         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-LocalUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewLocalUserCommand

Add-LocalGroupMember : WIN-JBOS5873GKP\dawsG01 ya es un miembro del grupo Administradores.
En línea: 5 Carácter: 1
+ Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administradores" -Member "dawsG01";
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (Administradores:String) [Add-LocalGroupMember], MemberExistsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MemberExists,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddLocalGroupMemberCommand
```

He intentado a guardar las contraseñas predefinidas en variables y también a introducirlas directamente como un *string*, pero obtengo el mismo error.

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. He añadido una respuesta a tu pregunta, pero te pido por favor que no publiques código o errores como imagenes. Publica directamente el texto del código fuente y el texto de los errores. Por favor edita tu pregunta para hacer ese cambio. Para más información, puedes leer [ask]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El cmdlet `New-LocalUser` requiere una contraseña proporcionada como un *string seguro*. Para convertir texto plano en un *string seguro* utiliza el cmdlet [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-6), puedes almacenar el resultado en una variable y luego utilizar esa variable para llamar a `New-LocalUser`.

```
$Secure_String_Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssW0rD!" -AsPlainText -Force
```

El uso de los parámetros `-AsPlainText -Force` es necesario (ambos) para crear un *string seguro* a partir de una contraseña en texto plano.

El script, completo, podría quedar algo como:

```
Clear-host
$Usuario = "prueba"
$SSPwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Usuario -AsPlainText -Force
New-LocalUser -Name $Usuario -Password $SSPwd -Description "Usuario de prueba"
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administradores" -Member $usuario
```